# How to better structure a chain of Observables (and exit if first returns null)

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

I have a functional method to retrieve an observable array of Requests, flatten it into a stream and then chain 3 other observables to retrieve 3 objects for each request (to replace the ids retrieved on the first observable). I have only included 2 in the code as it is too long.

Because the initial Observable can return empty if there are no requests, I was forced to add an if check at every step to return an observable of(null), if they recieved null from the previous step. This was so the chain would complete one way or another.

I am quite new to Angular and RXJS and would like to know a better and leaner way to handle this!

I feel the solution could be iff() discovered from a previous question, but not sure how to implement without breaking the chain after the first observable returns. I need that result to determine whether to carry out the subsequent steps.

I considered ForkJoin also after the first observable completes, as the order of the 3 nested is not really important. But similar to the iff() problem, not sure how to implement mid-chain.

```
// the array to be populated and returned at the end
const requestsArr: Request[] = [];

return this.fetchRequests().pipe(
  mergeMap(requests => {
     if (!requests || !requests.length) {
        return of(null);
     }
     return requests.map(request => request);
  }),
  mergeMap(request => {
     if (!request) {return of(null);}
     return this.patientsService.getPatient(request.patientId, request.requesterId).pipe(
        map(patient => {
           request.patientId = patient;
           return request;
         })
     );
   }),
   mergeMap(request => {
     if (!request) { return of(null);}
     return this.contactsService.getContact(request.requesterId).pipe(
       map(requester => {
         request.requesterId = requester;
         // construct request object and push onto array
         return requestsArr;
       })
     );
   })
);
```

The method works, but i would like to know a better and leaner approach or retrieving the data from one observable, and using that result to determine whether to call the others.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

return of();

This will stop the chain of observables

But 'return of(null);' will return the null value to the next chain of observable.

Comment: This is not an answer, of 'operator' emit variable amount of values in a sequence and then emits a complete notification, the question is asking how to end the observable. check [this](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/of)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `filter` to the `pipe`, as the first operator

The `fetchRequests` will not emit if the filter returns false - but would emit once the array had values. You'd need to test it with the different combinations e.g. null, [values], null, [values] to be sure it wasn't affecting anything else. It can cause issues for instance if you are using `fetchRequests` in a `combineLatest`